# HP LaserJet 4M printing gray background

Tags: hp-laserjet, cartridge, background

My HP LaserJet 4M just started printing gray background on my documents.

I have cleaned both the printer and toner cartridge inside. Toner cartridge is recycled but relatively new.

I have never had this issue before.

Comment: I remember this being a driver issue. I don't remember _how_ I solved it (it was too long ago), but it might have involved installing a completely different driver version instead of the one "recommended" by Windows Update.